# $f$ is a convex function. There is a point $x \in (a, b)$ such that for every $y \in [a, b]$ $f(x) ≥ f(y)$. Prove that $f$ is a contant function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f : [a; b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. It is known that there exists a point $x \in
(a, b)$ such that for every $y \in [a, b]$ it is true that $f(x) ≥ f(y)$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: for $x, y \in (a,b)$, $x<y$, let $m_{xy} = \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$. For $x<y<z$, try to show that $m_{xy} \leq m_{yz}$ if $f$ is convex. Once you have this, fix $y = x_0$ where $f$ attains global maximum at $x_0$ and see what happens.

Comment: I ma trying to do what you said. I took a point in the middle to convex inequalities and I try to plug them into the inequality fo lagranges but somehow I cant get anythink meaningful.

Comment: Once you have that (1) $m_{xx_0} \leq m_{x_0z}$, you can do the following. By the given assumption, $f(x), f(z) \leq f(x_0)$. Hence, (2) $m_{x_0z} \leq 0 \leq m_{xx_0}$ holds. Combining (1) and (2), $m_{xx_0} = m_{x_0z} = 0$. Choice of $x, z$ is arbitrary, so you have the desired result.

Comment: If you are wondering why (1) holds, for $x<y<z$, convince yourself that $\lambda = \frac{y-x}{z-x}$ satisfies: $f(y) \leq (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(z)$ by convexity of $f$. Now, this implies (1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m \in (a,b)$ is such that $f(m) \ge f(y)$ for all $y \in [a,b]$, this means that $f(m)$ is the maximum value of $f$ in the interval $[a,b]$. And since $f$ is convex (the shape of the curve is concave upward), or $f'' \ge 0$, then it means $f$ can only attains maximum value at the end points, either $a$ or $b$ or both. But $m \ne a$ and $m \ne b$, so contradiction.

Comment: Now I will try to solve it myself with hints from James Chung, thank you.

Comment: @mathbb do you understand my answer?

Comment: Yes, it is much easier and much more intuitive than inequalities of covex functions (Jensen) and continous functions (Lagrange).

Comment: @mathbb just be careful that $f$ is not necessarily (twice) differentiable everywhere on $(a,b)$. Other than that, you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, let $x_1\in[a,x)$ and $x_2\in(x,b]$ so that $x_1<x<x_2$.

Since $f(x)\geq f(y)$ for all $y\in[a,b]$, then by definition of convexity $$0\leq\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x-x_1}\leq\frac{f(x)-f(x_2)}{x-x_2}\leq 0$$
which implies $$f(x_1)=f(x)=f(x_2)$$

So for any $x_1\in[a,x)$ and for any $x_2\in(x,b]$, we have $f(x_1)=f(x)=f(x_2)$, thus $f$ is constant and is equal to $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x_1 <x, x_2> x$

There must exist a $t\in(0,1)$ such that $x=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$.

Then

$$f(x)\le tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(x_2)\\ \rightarrow\\(1-t)f(x)\le(1-t)f(x_2)\\ \rightarrow \\ f(x) \le f(x_2).$$

But we know that $f(x_2)\le f(x)$, hence $f(x)=f(x_2)$.

Also

$$f(x)\le t f(x_1) +(1-t)f(x_2) \le t f(x_1) + (1-t) f(x) \\ \rightarrow \\tf(x) \le t f(x_1) \\ \rightarrow \\f(x)\le f(x_1),$$
so $f(x)=f(x_1).$

Now we have that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x)$.